# Copy Data - How to skip Identity columns

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm designing a Copy Data task where the Sink SQL Server table contains an Identity column. The Copy Data task always wants me to map that column when, in my opinion, it should just not include the column in the list of columns to map. Does anyone know how I can get the ADF Copy Data task to ignore Sink Identity columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using copy data tool, and in your sql server, the ID is set as auto-increment, then it should not show out at the mapping step. Please tell us if it is not the case.

If you are using the create pipeline/dataset, you could just go to the sink dataset schema tab, remove the id column. And then go to the copy activity mapping tab, click import schemes again. ID column should has disappeared now.

Comment: I'm using the Copy Data tool and my Identity column shows up in the mapping section of the Activity.

Comment: Even though this is old, I want to add that when I remove the id column in the sink dataset schema, when I go back to the pipeline and import the schemas again, it adds back the id column to the sink dataset. My workaround was that I had to remove the id column from the sink dataset and then manually uncheck the column in the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You could include a SET_IDENTITY_INSERT_ON statement for the given table before executing the copy step. After completed, set it to OFF.

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question.